# How to open the desighner view in visual studio 10

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have create a new project in visual studio 12. Now how I proceed to **Designer View** page where you see all the buttons and stuff.
Help me guys..

Comment: Going to need a bit more information here.  What type of object are you trying to open the designer view on?  Is it a WinForm, WPF, Asp.Net app, etc ...  What are you doing that you expect the designer to show up for that isn't?